# Automatically tag RSS entry depending on keyword

Tags: elfeed

I'm trying to automatically set an important tag to some entries when the title or the content.

So here is what I have:

```lisp
;; important keywords
(setq elfeed-keywords '("gRPC" "Protobuf" "Protocol Buffers"))

;; iterate of important keywords and check if content or title contains one of them
;; if it's the case -> add important tag
(defun elfeed-filter(entry)
  (dolist (keyword elfeed-keywords)
    (when (or (string-match-p (regexp-quote keyword) (elfeed-entry-title entry))
              (string-match-p (regexp-quote keyword) (elfeed-entry-content entry)))
      (elfeed-tag entry 'important))))

;; add hook for when elfeed receives a new entry
(add-hook 'elfeed-new-entry-hook #'elfeed-filter)

;; Change color for important entry
(defface important-elfeed-entry
  '((t :foreground "#f77"))
  "Marks an important Elfeed entry.")

;; Add important tag to elfeed
(push '(important important-elfeed-entry)
  elfeed-search-face-alist)
```

this doesn't change the color of the entries to #f77 when they have a keyword in the title and/or content. I tried the `string-match-p` part in `ielm` and it seems that the matching part works well. Could you help me find what I don't get right here (I'm relatively new to elisp) ?

For testing purpose, you can use the following RSS feed: [gRPC blog](https://grpc.io/blog/index.xml)

### Edit

Thanks to Phil Hudson in the comments, I found how to use `edebug`. It turned out that the content is an object and we can't do a string-match-p on it. So for now, I'm using the following:

```lisp
(defun elfeed-filter(entry)
  (dolist (keyword elfeed-keywords)
    (when (string-match-p (regexp-quote keyword) (elfeed-entry-title entry))
      (elfeed-tag entry 'important)
      (return))))
```

This is changing the color of my important entries but this is only doing it for title with the keyword. I still am interested in how to solve that with content.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "doesn't work" - what happens, what did you expect/want t happen?

Comment: @Drew this should be clearer now but basically elfeed doesn't recolor the entries even if a keyword is in the content and/or title

Comment: Thx............

Comment: You say you are new to Elisp; have you had a chance to get to know `edebug`? That should make it relatively easy to see what is going wrong. `(info "(elisp) Edebug")`